# Replace character values across several columns at once

Tags: r

How do I replace values such as ORANGE, Orangee, ornage, etc across 50 columns at once? Our columns are "Sname1", until "Sname5" and then repeated for 3 months "3Sname1" until "24Sname5". I am very bad at loops how can I target all columns at once perhaps containing Namex?

And how do I replace all these values across all these columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this, which uses `lapply` and `gsub` (with `paste`) to replace a specific set of strings (`finds`) across selected columns (`replace_cols`) with `Sname` somewhere in the column name using `grep`.

I assume you wanted misspellings (ORANGE, Orangee, ornage, etc) replaced with the correct spelling of "orange" - if not, change "orange" in the `gsub` function to whatever you want.

Data

```
df <- data.frame(id = paste0("ID",1:4),
                 Sname1 = c("Apple", "Orangee", "ORANGE", "ornage"),
                 Sname2 = c("Apple", "Orangee", "ORANGE", "ornage"),
                 Sname3 = c("Apple", "Orangee", "ORANGE", "ornage"),
                 other = LETTERS[1:4])
```

Code

```
finds <- c("ORANGE", "Orangee", "ornage")

replace_cols <- grep("Sname", names(df))

df[replace_cols] <- lapply(df[replace_cols], 
                           function(x) gsub(paste(finds, collapse = "|"), 
                                            "orange", x, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
   id Sname1 Sname2 Sname3 other
1 ID1  Apple  Apple  Apple     A
2 ID2 orange orange orange     B
3 ID3 orange orange orange     C
4 ID4 orange orange orange     D
```

If this doesn't answer your question completely please modify the question to include reproducible data specific to your needs.

Comment: Hi this is amazing thank you! 
The only issue I am having still is that for some of the replacements it takes part of the word for example "Orange t10c10" will be automatically changed to "AppleT10:C10" even though I put the exact words I wanted to be changed (apple t10:c10) -> "AppleT10:C10"

Comment: Hi @NoobR - if you can provide some sample data where I can recreate your issue, I'd be happy to help. I cant seem to recreate it on my end. Could you edit your question to provide the structure of your data using `dput(your_data)`? It's very difficult to help otherwise.

Comment: HI apologies I don't even know how to do this. Is there a way to tell R to "match entire cell contents"? For example my data might be in the form of "Orangee apple 35" and it replaces to "Orange apple 35". But I want it to replace the entire contents of the cell with the new value and not leave any other characters. Hopes this makes sense

Comment: try `df[replace_cols] <- lapply(df[replace_cols], function(x) {x[grep(paste(finds, collapse = "|"), x)] <- "orange"; x})`